# Footcite inside a figure : strange behaviour

Tags: floats, citing, footnotes, biber

I am struggled with a mysterious bug I never had never seen:
I used a `biber` bibliography and I would like to set up figures with references.

When I write this:

```
\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=\textheight,keepaspectratio]{illustrations/SchemaNodejs}
    \footcite{NodejsIllustrations}
    \caption{Du Javascript aussi bien côté serveur que client}
\end{figure}
\clearpage
```

I got this: (no footnote but there is a number) :
[image: Bug]

Of course, I tried outside the figure and it works. How to make it working inside ?

Thanks

PS: Solutions like `\protect` doesn't seem to work for my case.

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Can you add compilable with adding a minimal working example ([MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)). Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Do you think that your readers will spot the footnote number? I don't think so. The citation would better go in the description of the figure.

Comment: Either in caption or not, it just not working .. I just want to find out why ...

Comment: Both figures and footnotes are floats.  You can't start a float inside a float.  You might be able to use \afterpage{\clearpage ...) and add both the figure and the footnote on the same page (see afterpage package).